# Remove element from useState array by index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, use-state

SOLUTION: Update the key value for the input element to refresh the default value => content of the input element. Deleting an element from the array DID work. Thanks for your help!
src: [https://thewebdev.info/2022/05/12/how-to-fix-react-input-defaultvalue-doesnt-update-with-state-with-javascript/#:~:text=state%20with%20JavaScript%3F-,To%20fix%20React%20input%20defaultValue%20doesn't%20update%20with%20state,default%20value%20of%20the%20input](https://thewebdev.info/2022/05/12/how-to-fix-react-input-defaultvalue-doesnt-update-with-state-with-javascript/#:%7E:text=state%20with%20JavaScript%3F-,To%20fix%20React%20input%20defaultValue%20doesn%27t%20update%20with%20state,default%20value%20of%20the%20input).

I got an useState array in my code which represents a lisst of students:
`const [students, setStudents] = useState([""]);`
This array gets mapped to student elements:
`{students.map((student, index) => <Student setStudents={setStudents} students={students} id={index} key={index} content={student} />)}` I also got an AddStudent element which adds students to the array.

```js
function AddStudent(props) {

    const {setStudents} = props;

    return (
        <button className="change-student add-student" onClick={() => {
            setStudents((students) => [...students, ""])
        }}>
            +
        </button>
    );
}
```

The RemoveStudent component is supposed to remove a student by its index in the array. I've tried many different ways but none worked correctly. How can I get it to work? Here is my code:

```js
function RemoveStudent(props) {
    const {students, setStudents, id} = props;

    return (
        <button className="change-student remove-student" onClick={() => {
            let data = students;
            if(id > -1) {
                data.splice(id, 1);
            }
            console.log(data)
            // setStudents(data)
            // alternative:
            // setStudents(students.filter(index => index !== id)); // removes the last element in the list
            // doesn't work properly
        }}>
            -
        </button>
    )
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What value did you set for a "student"?

Comment: The Problem is that I got an array from the input elements. For example (1,2,3). When I now delete the second value (2) the array changes but the input's default values doesn't. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things should be noted here:

While updating react state arrays, use methods that *return a new array* (`map`, `filter`, `slice`, `concat`),
rather than ones that modify the existing array (`splice`, `push`, `pop`, `sort`).

While updating React state using its previous value, the *callback argument* should be used for the state setter. Otherwise you may get stale values. ([See React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)).

```
if(id > -1) {
    setStudents(students=> students.filter((s,i)=>(i != id)))
}
```

Consult this [article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/), for a complete reference about how to update React state arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the solution was to add the key property to the input element for the default value to change

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the `students` array first and then try removing the student by index. I assume by `id` you mean index at which to remove the student. Then you can try something like:

```js
function RemoveStudent(props) {
    const {students, setStudents, id} = props;

    return (
        <button
            className="change-student remove-student"
            onClick={() => {
                if(id > -1) {
                    const data = [...students]; // making a copy
                    data.splice(id, 1);         // removing at index id
                    console.log(data)
                    setStudents(data)
                }
            }}
        >
            -
        </button>
    )
}
```

With `array.filter()` you have a mistake in how you pass callback to `filter()` method. Please try the following:

```js
setStudents(students.filter((,index) => index !== id));
```

Notice the index is second param of the callback so I used a `,` before index.

Comment: Sorry the, first solution updates the array but my elements are not being updated.

Comment: Please remember to put comma in callback params i.e. `(,index) => ...`. This is because `array.filter()` callback has first current element as first param and index as second param. With the first one, please check if `id` prop has the right index of the student.

Comment: But then the comma gets marked as an error => any
Expression expected

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the solution was to add the key property to the input element for the default value to change

Answer (score 1):

After @Irfanullah Jan 's answer you should make sure how you show the student.

Here is the simple example:

```
const [students, setStudents] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

  return (
    <div>
      {students.map((student, index) => {
        return <div>{student}</div>; // show the value not the index
      })}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          let id = 1;
          const copy = [...students];
          copy.splice(id, 1)
          console.log(copy)
          setStudents(copy);
        }}
      >
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

The code above will delete the student of "index==1"

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the solution was to add the key property to the input element for the default value to change